# How do I present an open folder selection dialog in Perl?

Tags: perl, folderbrowserdialog, fileopendialog

How do I open folder selection dialog in Perl?

Comment: Which GUI toolkit are you using? (Tk, Win32::GUI, wxPerl, etc.)

Comment: Voting to close as "not a real question" since Greg doesn't seem to be willing to give us any more information.

Comment: @Manni:  That may be so, but this can still be a useful question, as there are now answer examples for Tk and Win32::GUI ...

Comment: I suspect he doesn't have any GUI toolkit yet.

Answer (score 7):

Depends on the GUI system you're using, and perhaps the platform.  For example, on Windows and using `Win32::GUI`, you can use `GetOpenFileName`:

```
# $main is your main window...
$my_file = $main->GetOpenFileName(
    -title => 'Select a file...',
    -file => 'default.file',
);
```

Answer (score 7):

Most [portable](http://matrix.cpantesters.org/?dist=Tk) (at least compared to [ot](http://matrix.cpantesters.org/?dist=Wx)[he](http://matrix.cpantesters.org/?dist=Gtk2)[rs](http://matrix.cpantesters.org/?dist=Win32::GUI)):

```
use Tk;
my $dir = Tk::MainWindow->new->chooseDirectory;
```

Of course, if you're actually using Tk in the rest of your program, you should call `chooseDirectory` on a proper parent widget instead of the one constructed and destructed here.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to check out the GUI bindings in [wxPerl](http://wxperl.sourceforge.net/).